# How to return different values for different input in mock?

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var o1 = new XmlDocument();
        var o2 = new XmlDocument();

        var mock = new Mock<ITestInterface>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.TestMethod(o1)).Returns(1);
        mock.Setup(m => m.TestMethod(o2)).Returns(2);

        Assert.AreEqual(1, mock.Object.TestMethod(o1));
        Assert.AreEqual(2, mock.Object.TestMethod(o2));
    }
}

public interface ITestInterface
{
    int TestMethod(object input);
}
```

Why mock always returns second value? If I switched XmlDocument to anything else (object, StringBuilder etc) it would work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I would have assumed it would work as you expected as well, but I also get the same results.  However if you instead do your setup as below, it will work as you want it to.

```
mock.Setup(m => m.TestMethod(It.Is<XmlDocument>(y => ReferenceEquals(o1, y)))).Returns(1);
mock.Setup(m => m.TestMethod(It.Is<XmlDocument>(y => ReferenceEquals(o2, y)))).Returns(2);
```

Something else I noticed as I tested further is that if you set the `InnerXml`, everything works as you originally setup.

```
var doc1 = new XmlDocument { InnerXml = "<root1 />" };
var doc2 = new XmlDocument { InnerXml = "<root2 />" };;
mock.Setup(x => x.TestMethod(doc1)).Returns(1);
mock.Setup(x => x.TestMethod(doc2)).Returns(2);

Console.WriteLine($"{mock.Object.TestMethod(doc1)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{mock.Object.TestMethod(doc2)}");
```

It even works if you set both `InnerXml` values to be identical strings.  Its really a mystery and I've been unable to explain it.

Comment: (I deleted my first comment because it was wrong.) It is really strange that the original code does not work since `System.Xml.XmlDocument` does not override `Equals` (and its base class does not either) and does not implement (directly or indirectly) `IEquatable<>`. So why is it treated differently than `StringBuilder`, for example?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I had thought maybe Moq is trying to help by looking at the XML contained without the XmlDocument.  I think there's a good argument that even if the references are different, if the XML is identical, they are the same object logically speaking.  But apparently setting InnerXml to anything makes everything work correctly.

Comment: Interesting. It feels like there is a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and experience the same issue. Running your code exactly how you posted fails on the first Assert with `Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<1>. Actual:<2>.`. When I change o1 and o2 to `object` instead of `XmlDocument` it worked as expected.

Strangely enough, changing the 2 setup lines to the following will cause it to produce correct results:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.TestMethod(It.Is<XmlDocument>(x => x == o1))).Returns(1);
mock.Setup(m => m.TestMethod(It.Is<XmlDocument>(x => x == o2))).Returns(2);
```

This is strange because I believe that your 2 setup lines are supposed to behave exactly like mine, yet mine work correctly in this case while yours don't. I assume that there is a difference which I'm not aware of or that there is a bug with Moq that causes this.

Comment: This is really the same as Andy's answer. This works (as does Andy's) even if you use `It.Is<object>(x => x == o1))` with `object` instead of `XmlDocument`. The same overload of `operator ==` (the pre-defined one `bool operator==(object, object)` that just does reference-equals) is used anyway.